# How to connect a program running on my computer to an external web server?

Tags: c, webserver

Let's say I want to code a very efficient program (in terms of execution time) in C and to display its output on a specific website; it will be executed everytime a client makes a specific request (i.e. clicking on a button). This program will run on my computer, but its output needs to be sent to the server that hosts this website (and the server is only running Apache). 
I have read about CGIs, but they are supposed to be outdated and to have very slow time responses, so is there any specific protocol (or anything else) that I should learn for making my aim possible?

Comment: [Module mod-fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html)

Comment: "*client makes a specific request (i.e. clicking on a button).*" where is this button located? In a page sent to the client by this Apache installation?

Comment: @AlterMann Now why didn't I see your tiny message; Okay +1 on FastCGI, and a true proxy might do the trick too.

Comment: @alk This button can either be located in a page deployed to the client's browser by a PHP script running in this Apache installation or just raw HTML (if I'm understanding well your question).

Comment: @AlterMann I didn't hear about FastCGI before, I will take a look on it :) Thanks!

Comment: How do plan to forward the client-side click-event form the receiving Apache  to your (3rd?) machine?